# Why does Promise.all() throw an exception even if I .catch() it?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, unhandled-promise-rejection

Running the code

```
Promise.all(new Promise((res, rej) => rej('Failure!')))
.catch(() => console.log("It's all okay."))
```

in Node v12.19.0 logs `It's all okay.` to the console but still throws an exception. Why is that? I would have expected the same behaviour as when I run

```
new Promise((res, rej) => rej('Failure!'))
.catch(() => console.log("It's all okay."))
```

This will also log `It's all okay.` to the console but does not throw an exception.

How can I catch the rejection in Promise.all()?

Full console output:

```
> Promise.all(new Promise((res, rej) => rej('Failure!'))).catch(() => console.log("It's all okay."))
Promise { <pending> }
> It's all okay.
(node:2872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Failure!
(node:2872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)

> new Promise((res, rej) => rej('Failure!')).catch(() => console.log("It's all okay."))
Promise { <pending> }
> It's all okay.
```

Comment: The argument to `Promise.all()` should be an array of promises, not a single promise.

Comment: `Promise.all(ARRAY_OF_PROMISE_HERE)`

Comment: Thanks. My assumption that `Promise.all(promise1, promise2, ...)` should work was wrong. But why than does it fire the catch on rejection even if its not an array?

Comment: Maybe use `.catch((err) => console.log(err))` instead of saying that "*It's all okay.*" :-P

Comment: The unhandled rejection comes from the `new Promise((res, rej) => rej('Failure!'))` which is not handled anywhere, not from the `Promise.all()` (which you *did* handle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) in the comments...

If you execute your first bit of code without the catch statement (or actually print the errors you catch) you'll see what is happening.

```js
Promise.all(new Promise((res, rej) => rej('Failure!')))
```

Returns:

```js
Promise {<rejected>: TypeError}
Uncaught (in promise) Failure!
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:9
```

Notice the first error is the error we throw by rejecting the promise.

The second error comes from not using `Promise.all()` correctly, which is the error you were catching.

The error we throw by rejecting the promise is never caught because of the incorrect usage of the `Promise.all()` method.

---

Now, let's test out the code with our promise inside an array, which is the correct usage of `Promise.all()`, as pointed out by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) in the comments.

```js
Promise.all([new Promise((res, rej) => rej('Failure!'))])
    .catch(() => console.log("It's all okay."))
```

Returns:

```
Promise {<fulfilled>}
It´s all okay.
```

So, we are successfully catching the rejected promise error.

Also worth noting, the final promise returned is the promise that the `catch()` method returns after execution. Which is fulfilled since we successfully executed the catch statement, although the promise that `Promise.all()` actually returns is rejected.